# How to add Yammer app for Sharepoint 2013 Foundation (the app is grayed out)

Tags: 2013, error, yammer

I already have access to the Sharepoint Store and I am able to download apps.
However, I see most of them grayed out and, once downloaded, I cannot install them. 
I get the error message:

> Sorry, this app is not supported on your server

I get this issue with yammer, but also with any other app.

Anyone knows what I am supposed to do in order to make this working?

Edit: I am not able to find the app package (.app file) where is this file located in my server?

Answer (score 1):

Please try these steps

- Leave this page open in the browser for the app dependency table located about half way through the article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/jj819804.aspx
- Find the app package, rename the .app file extension to .zip.
- Right click the .zip file and extract the contents.
- Open the AppManfiest.xml file in Notepad.
- Search for the AppPrerequisites tag.
- Using the table specified in Step 1, ensure that the prereqs meet the specs of the SharePoint instance you are working with.

Click [here](http://www.sharepointsecurity.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-development/sorry-this-app-is-not-supported-on-your-server-on-multi-tenant-farm-on-sharepoint-foundation/) for details

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves your query

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. However I am not able to find the App package (.app file) where is this file located in my server? Thanks very much.